# Getting my form data to post to mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

Pretty new to php/mysql and jquery, and I'm having trouble getting my form data to upload to my mysql db. I've tried a few different approaches and done my research, but none of the suggestions I've found online are working for me, which is why I'm posting here. So here's my most recent failed approach:

in my index file:

```
 <head>

 ...

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Announcement form AJAX submit
    $('#announcementForm').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                if (data.error) {
                    $('#error').css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                    $('#note').show();
                    $('#error').hide();
                    $('#fields').hide();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

 </head>
 <body>

 ...

 <form class="dl_form" id="announcementForm" method="post">
            <dl>
                <dt>Announcement</dt>
                <dd><textarea id="Announcement" sytle="width: 300px; height: 150px;" name="Announcement"></textarea></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt>Announcement Type:</dt>
                <dd><input type="radio" name="Type" value="schedule">Scheduling</input></dd>
                <dd><input type="radio" name="Type" value="general">General</input></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt></dt>
                <dd><input type="submit" value="submit" /></dd>
            </dl>
        </form>

        <div id="note">
            <p>Announcement posted successfully!"</p>
        </div>
        <div id="error">You haven't completed all of the required fields</div>
```

And then in my ajax.php file I have (some lines have been replaced with "######" for security reasons):

```
 <?php
//database credentials
$server    = '######';
$username   = '######';
$password   = '######';
$database   = '######';
$connect    = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password ) or die(mysql_error.'error connecting to db');

//select database
mysql_select_db($database, $connect) or die(mysql_error.'error selecting db');

//$typeValue = $('input:radio[name=Type]:checked').val());

if (!empty($_POST)){
    $Announcement   = $_POST['Announcement'];
    $Type           = $_POST['Type'];

    if (!empty($Announcement) && !empty($Type) )
    {
        //insert data into db
        mysql_query("INSERT into announcements (AnnouncementID, Type, Announcement)
        VALUES ('', '".$Type."', '".$Announcement."')") or die(mysql_error());
    }else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'error' => true,
            'msg'   => "You haven't completed all required fields!"
        ));
        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Any help you guys can provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO Jay Blanchard:

I just ran the console in my browser. The only error I'm getting is:

```
 SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'
```

in reference to the first line of my JS:

```
 $function() {
 ...
```

UPDATE 2:

Just updated my code to reflect my most recent changes...before I could at least trigger the submit click even and the fields would empty, indicating that at least something was happening. With my new round of changes however, not even that triggers, so I'm still pretty stuck

Comment: Don't use mysql_*. It is deprecated and insecure, and will be removed from future versions of PHP. Also, you are wide open to SQL Injection. You need to use PDO or MySQLi and use prepared statements.

Comment: You didn't mention what is the problem?

Comment: Also you Should remove AnnouncementID from your query if in database it is auto increment, because db will warn you for incorrect integer value for column AnnouncementID

Comment: To see what is happening use your browser's console. Errors will be revealed to you there and help you to troubleshoot the actual issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your php you've made a mistake with your `echo` statement its not `jason_encode` instead its `json_encode`.

Additionally

Also you Should remove `AnnouncementID` from your query if in database it is auto increment, because db will warn you for incorrect integer value for column `AnnouncementID`.

**EDIT:** In your php part in statement

```
mysql_query("INSERT into announcements (AnnouncementID, Type, Announcement)
            VALUES ('', '".$Type."', '".$Announcement"')") or die(mysql_error());
```

You are forgetting a concatenation operator `.` after `'".$Announcement` which should be

```
mysql_query("INSERT into announcements (AnnouncementID, Type, Announcement)
            VALUES ('', '".$Type."', '".$Announcement."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

and in your jquery instead of

```
$function() {
```

use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: Hey pronox, thanks for the help. Both of those were oversights on my part and I've fixed them, however my problem was not solved. Do you see any other issues. Like I said in the update I just posted, my script is returning an error, but I don't see where I'm missing a ' ; '

Comment: @wrigley06 check my edit you were missing `.` in your query ;)

Comment: Your going to hate this, but I fixed that and am still not able to to insert the form data. I'm less sure of my jquery script than I am my php...is it possible that that's where the issue is? Thanks again for helping out

Comment: Oh my bad there is one more issue with your jquery check updated answer in a sec

Comment: i have test this code i changed this jquery one line, db credentials and that dot and with me it works like a charm.

Comment: Okay, now I'm just getting frustrated because I've made all of those changes and now I can't even trigger the submit event. Give me about two minutes...I'm going to repost the code I have with the changes I've made

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48514/discussion-between-pronox-and-wrigley06)